# Dependence of sale-price on bargaining ability

Tags: reference-request, bargaining

Consider a single seller offering a single item to a single buyer. If the seller's value is $s$ and the buyer's value is $b$ and $s<b$, then every price between $s$ and $b$ is individually rational.

In practice, the actual price depends, at least on part, on the "bargaining expertise" of both sides. Some people know better than others to haggle, or to hide their private information, or to pressurize the other side in other ways, in order to get a better price for them. What are some research papers on the effects of such factors on the trade price?